# Firestore console changes does not trigger snapshotChanges subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to subscribe to a document in Firestore by using AngularFire. When I edit my document through Firestore console, I cannot see any difference in the pulled data even after refreshing my local. DocumentChangeAction.type is still "added" after modification.

Doesn't console changes suppose to trigger "modified" action even for manual updates ?

Thanks.

```
retrieveUserPosts666 (uid: string, page, lastKey,now:number, nowBefore30:number) {

        let plizt = [];

        return this.afs.collection<any>("uk", ref => {

            let query : firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;

            query = query.where('uid','==',uid);
            query = query.orderBy('postdate','desc');
            query = query.startAt(lastKey).limit(page);

            return query;

        }).snapshotChanges().map(x=> {

            x.forEach((post, index) => {

                plizt.push({
                    "key": post.payload.doc.id,
                    "itm": post.payload.doc.data(),
                    "city" : this.retrieveBeatifulCityName(post.payload.doc.get('city')),
                    "cut_en" : post.payload.doc.get('description_en').substring(0,100) + "..."
                })

            });
            return plizt;
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced "AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()" with just "AngularFirestoreModule" in imports section of app.module.ts. Resolved now. Please refer to following page. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)